# lightning:datatable disable checkbox rows based on if a field has a value

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-datatable

In lightning:datatable, I'm looking to disable specific rows' checkboxes if one of the other column fields returned in my dataset is not empty.  Am I do this without disabling the entire checkbox column like in the hideCheckboxColumn attribute?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think you are able to do anything more than static row level actions at this point of time.